# Erro para chamar Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou com problema para chamar outra `activity`. Segue código da Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
}

public void entrarOnClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
    } 

}
```

e o androidmanifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Principal"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu" 
        android:label="Menu" > 
    </activity>
```

segue o logcat:

```
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     ... 11 more
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.radiosu/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     at com.example.radiosu.Principal.entrarOnClick(Principal.java:32)
09-23 14:03:21.527: E/AndroidRuntime(2464):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Bem Vindo ao StackOverFlow em Português. Qual o erro que você está tendo?

Comment: Porque é que existe uma função dentro de uma função aí? entrarOnClick não deveria estar dentro do onCreate

Comment: Era uma pergunta. Faltou o ?. Esse problema já foi resolvido mais abaixo.

Comment: Está a tentar usar outra class Menu em vez da sua. Está a ver `Menu.class`? Está a apontar para android.view.Menu em vez da sua class Menu. Em vez de usar `Menu.class` experimente usar `com.seupackage.Menu.class`

Comment: deu certo agora, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Está a tentar declarar uma função dentro de outra função.
Altere o seu código para este:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

}
public void entrarOnClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
    }
```

Alem disso está a tentar apontar para o Menu do android.view e não o seu. Use o caminho completo da sua classe em vez de Menu.class. Algo como `com.example.radiosu.Menu.class` provavelmente.

Comment: as {}. Quando diz que é iniciante em programação android não está a querer dizer iniciante em programação em geral certo?

Comment: detalhe tão sutil que passou batido. - vou remover o comentário acima e depois removo esse. Abraçs!

Comment: Lembre-se de marcar a resposta como correta se esta resolveu o seu problema e tenha um bom dia.

Comment: Não posso fazer isso.. pq não sou o criador do tópico.  :)

Comment: Foi um comentário para a comunidade em geral caso o criador se lembre de ler as respostas às suas perguntas :)

Comment: era um detalhe que eu não tinha visto, mas agora está aparecendo a mensagem de erro " unfortunately, app has stopped. Muito obrigado

Comment: Então o melhor a fazer é atualizar a sua pergunta e colocar o stacktrace do Logcat para podermos saber o que se está a passar.

Answer (score 0):

Não seria porque você não clicaria em algo "vazio". Tente setar a imagem e ou botão pelo seu id, internamente ao `onCreateView()`, usando `onClickListener()` (desta forma é certeza que vai funcionar):

```
  findViewById(R.id.bt_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        Intent it = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(it);
      }
    });
```

Vendo seu `AndroidManifest` ele abre em Menu, não abria primeiramente na `Activity Main`  (a atividade principal, base para as demais)?